# My server starts but when I test it on Postman it just loops I checked the firewall and my connection but still nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

My server starts but when I test it on Postman it just keeps looping I checked the firewall and my connection but still nothing and it does not return any error message, if anyone can help me please

```js
    const express = require("express"); //import express
    const userRoutes = require("./routes/user.routes");
    const postRoutes = require("./routes/post.routes");
    require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config/.env" });
    require("./config/db");
    const { checkUser, requireAuth } = require("./middleware/auth.middleware"); //import express
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
    const cors = require("cors");
    
    const app = express();
    
    const corsOptions = {
         origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
         credentials: true,
         allowedHeaders: ["sessionId", "Content-Type"],
         exposedHeaders: ["sessionId"],
         methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
         preflightContinue: false, }; configuration de cors
    app.use(cors(corsOptions)); app.use(cors); utilisation de cors
    
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
     app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
     app.use(cookieParser());
    
    //routes
     app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
     app.use("/api/post", postRoutes);
    
    //jwt
     app.get("*", checkUser);
     app.get("/jwtid", requireAuth, (req, res) => {
         res.status(200).send(res.locals.user._id); });
    
    app.listen(6000, () => {
         console.log("serveur demarré sur 6000"); });
```

démarrage du serveur

Le serveur demarre mais aucun resultat losque j'essaie d'enregistrer un nouveau compte dans la base de données, quelqu'un peut m'aider svp?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to fix the formatting of your code, you can see how to do that in the [markdown docs for stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: How are you testing it? Do you start the server and then hit some API? Can you mention the steps?

Comment: on the terminal I run the "npm start" command and there the server starts, and then I go to postman and I insert the data that I want to enter into the database but there it just grinds and loops and there is no error message to be able to fix this

Comment: https://github.com/General243/MERN     here is the github link of the project